# Camera orientation and Object location identificaiton in 3D Coordinate system

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I am doing project on person re-identification within a single room with the concept of appearance model and  person actual location. My setup is, I have 3 camera inside a single room(overlapping). These cameras detect person and calculate  the appearance model for that person along with its exact location within the room in (x,y,z). My server in the cloud will maintain a feature list for each person in the room. I want to know if  hree cameras shooting on different direction on one object will be able to locate that object in exact same location or not. Given, I have camera  location in (xyz coordinate)  and object  2d Coordinate in  2D plane. My concern if, with this all information in hand, if three camera calculate  the person actual position relative to respective camera position, will all camera reports same location for that person.
If I am wrong, could you please help me what should  I aspect should I consider to make all camera report same exact location for an object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 3 cameras should be sufficient to locate an object in 3D space. If we know the (X,Y,Z) coordinates of each camera and the angle to the object from each camera, we can construct 3 lines each going thru a camera and towards the object. All 3 will only cross in one place - which is at the object.

Comment: Can you explain how to calculate object location from camera location and object 2D coordinate..?